# vsts build fails missing dll

Tags: visual-studio-2017, azure-devops

I have a local .Net Standard 2.0 library project and separate Xunit test project as part of a VS2017 solution.  Library and Xunit tests successfully build with VS2017 and tests all succeed.

I uploaded the Git repository to VSTS. I am attempting to Build the two projects and then run the tests.  The Restore step succeeds.  However, the Build step successfully compiles the library, but the tests fail because the reference to the library dll is not found.

I have searched the Internet and have not found anything that helps me solve this.  I assume that there is something simple to do that fixes this but ....

Comment: What dll is not found? What's the detail error message? Can you share the detail log on the OneDrive? (Set system.debug variable to true, then queue build)

Comment: As mentioned, the first build creates a dll, or does when I build the solution locally.  This first dll is then referenced by the second project, the tests.  In VSTS, the first dll is not found by the second project build.

Comment: Error is: "namespace" could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference where the namespace is the namespace of the first dll.

Comment: Can you share the detail log on the OneDrive? On the other hand, you may share the sample projects on the OneDrive.

Comment: Unfortunately, not anymore.  I split the two parts - library and tests - into two separate solutions.  Working now to get this working on VSTS.